# Hydrology Analysis via SAGA - what is the unit?

Tags: saga, hydrology, units, topographic-wetness-index

I did a couple of analysis via SAGA about an area in Iceland...I've never worked with SAGA before, could anyone tell me  what Units the numbers in the legends for "Catchment Area Recursive" and "topographic Wetness index" are?

Plus: why is the Strahler legend with decimals? shouldn't that be natural numbers?

Comment: It's been some time since I worked with SAGA, but here's a few thoughts to keep the discussion going: I would assume the units are the same as in (the coordinate system of) your input data. TWI, being an index based on logarithms, is probably unitless. Strahler is usually integers, have you checked if the data includes values with decimals or just the legend?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be just one question per question.